Jenkins Groovy - XmlParser: appending a node always adds an empty xmlns attribute
I'm desperately trying to find a way to append a node to an XML file without namespaces in Jenkins.
By using XmlSlurper it seems impossibile because of "non serializable" issues, even creating @NonCPS functions for everything: it simply behaves in a completely different - and unpredictable for me - way from regular Groovy, and everything I tried seems no way out.
By using XmlParser Node.appendNode() I can't get rid of the xmlns="" attribute on the upper added node, which gets added even though I istantiate the parser object with XmlParser(false, false). I couldn't remove that attribute even with Node.attributes().remove('xmlns').
Is there anybody out there who can tell how to append a node without an xmlns="" attribute with XmlParser?
Thanks in advance for any useful advice
